# Keras 3Dconvnet time-series issue

Tags: keras, convolution

I have a time-series of data and am running some very basic tests to get a feel for TensorFlow, Keras, Python, etc.

To setup the problem, I have a large amount of images whereby 7 images of data (with Cartesian dimensions 33 x 33) when accumulated should yield a single value. Therefore, the amount of 'x' data should be y*7 where y is the 'truth' data being trained with.

All of the training data is in entitled 'alldatax' which is a large matrix: [420420 x 33 x 33 x 7 x 1] where the dimensions are the total number of single images, x-dimension, y-dimension, number of images to be accumulated for a single 'truth' value, and then a final dimension necessary for 3D convolving.

The 'truth' matrix, alldatay, is a 1D matrix which is simply 420420 / 7 = 60060.

When running a simple convnet:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(33,33,7,1)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(16,(3,3,1), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (33,33,7,1)))
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((2,2,1)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(32,(3,3,1), activation = 'relu')) 
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling3D((2,2,1)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation = 'relu'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
model.fit(x = alldatax, y = alldatay,  batch_size = 1000, epochs = 50, verbose = 1, shuffle = False)
```

I get an error: ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 420420 input samples and 60060 target samples.

What needs to change to get the convnet to realize it needs 7*x for every y value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems to be wrong in your calculations.
You state that the neural net should take seven 33x33 images as one input example, so you set the input shape of the first layer to `(33,33,7,1)` which is right. This means for every 33x33x7x1 input there should be exactly one y value.

Since all of your data all your data comprises 420420 33x33x7x1 images there should be 420420 y values, not 60060.